# Ambiguous template instantiation

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, ambiguity

Can someone explain the ambiguity here?

```
template <typename...> struct thing;

template <typename... Rest>
struct thing<int&, Rest&...> {
    thing(int&, Rest&...) { }
};

template <typename First, typename... Rest>
struct thing<First&, Rest&...> {
    thing(First&, Rest&...) { }
};

int main() {
    int myint;
    char mychar;
    thing<int&, char&> t(myint, mychar);
}
```

Comment: well, which thing are you referring to?  The one that takes 1 + other args, or the one that takes 2 + other args?

Comment: Isn't the first specialization more specialized than the second?  It should take the first one automatically, right?

Comment: clang 6 has no issues with it.

Comment: This might be a compiler bug.

Comment: GCC 7.2 compains.  It works when I remove the references from the types though.

Comment: Reminds me of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892048/class-template-specialization-priority-ambiguity

Comment: Any workaround here if I must get this to work with GCC 7.2?  Perhaps using `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<First, int>>* = nullptr` somewhere?

Comment: You can have `template <typename ... Ts> struct thing<Ts&...> : thing_for_ref<Ts...> {}` (and then specialize `thing_for_ref`) as workaround.

Comment: A working workaround using SFINAE: https://wandbox.org/permlink/cPGy0K4I5BR2EWIm

Comment: The latest msvc (19.11.25547) also has no problems, at least after the variables are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

if you specialize on `int` instead of `int&` it works

```
template <typename...> struct thing;

template <typename... Rest>
struct thing<int, Rest...> {
    thing(int&, Rest&...) { }
};

template <typename First, typename... Rest>
struct thing<First, Rest...> {
    thing(First&, Rest&...) { }
};
```